# Problem Importing Web Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have created a web service in a virtual directory using VS 2008.  I have tested the service by going to the .asmx page and everything is working fine.  So I selected the "Add web reference" option under the solution and typed in the .asmx URL.  It found the web service  successfully and added the reference to the project.  However, when I try to import the service namespace using the same name as the directory under the "App_WebReferences" folder, it doesn't recognize the name and gives me an error if I try to import it.  Have I missed any steps in the process?

Comment: Namespace or type specified in the imports "SasService" doesn't contain any public members or cannot be found.

Comment: I just generated the proxy class manually through the VS 2008 Command Line tool and added it as an existing item to my web service project directory.  I rebuilt the web service, then went back to my client application and deleted and added the web reference again.  I am still not able to import it.

Comment: actually, you need to add the manual proxy as an existing item to the "client web application".

Comment: actually, you need to add the manually generated proxy class as an existing item to the "client web application".

Comment: once it is added, you can just import the namespace in the proxy.

Comment: Okay, I added the item to the client app - is there a specific folder I need to add the file to, or can it be added anywhere?  I thought the error had to do with not adding a "service reference", but I have added that as well, but still no luck with importing the web service namespace.  Is it a problem if the URL happens to be an IP address?  This whole process is way too complicated! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Try generating the proxy manually using the [wsdl](http://jlab.calumet.purdue.edu/theGateway/v2/0/doc/Instructions/ProxyClassInstructionsVS2005.htm) tool and adding the proxy class as an existing item to client web application project as mentioned in the link.

Something strange happening with proxy generation in your case from VS. Maybe an access issue.
If it happened fine, you should be able to find the VS generated proxy class under one of the sub-folders of 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ (for Asp.Net 2.0). Search for file names starting with App_WebReferences*.cs in the temporary folder.

---

When you added the web service, what is the name of the web reference you gave? Use the same web reference name in your import statement.

In this [link](http://digitalcolony.com/2007/08/consuming-web-service-in-aspnet.aspx), web reference name is `com.deepfitness` so you can `import com.deepfitness` namespace in your asp.net app.

Comment: Just to see if it was a problem with my web service, I added the deepfitness service (using "com.deepfitness") to my web references.  Then I created a new page and tried importing it, but it couldn't find that namespace and wouldn't let me import it.

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely certain click view all files in you web project and follow your reference in App_WebReferences down until you get to reference.cs open this and you can see the correct namespace.

Comment: I drilled down, but could not find a reference.cs file...by the way, I'm working in VB.NET.  The only files I found were the following: Service.disco, Service.discomap, and Service.wsdl.

Comment: Try this <project namespace>.<web reference name>

Imports ClassLibrary1.ServiceReference1

Public Class Class1

End Class